# Validity of Taylor's Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We all know the Taylor's series for $\ln(1+x)$ about $x=0$. Can this series be used to approximate $\ln(1+x)$ for any value of x?

I tried to find value of $\ln(3)=\ln(1+2)$ by using first four terms of the series but I got negative value. Where was my mistake?

Comment: The interval of convergence of the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$ is $(-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\log(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n (-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$

we can use the ratio test to determine radius of convergence:

$$\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right| = \frac{|x|^{n+1} n}{|x|^n (n+1)} = \frac{|x| n}{n+1}$$

Letting $n\to\infty$, this becomes

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\right| = |x| < 1$$

The end behaviour (i.e. at $x=-1,+1$) can be determined easily using the alternating series test and that the harmonic series diverges. Thus, the series converges for $x\in (-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanx! By the way, is there any graphical way too to backup the mentioned points?

Comment: @Mathematics Using complex analysis there is quite an elegant way. It turns out that the series for $f(z)$ centred at $z=z_0$ has a radius of convergence $R$ determined by the "distance" (i.e. magnitude of the difference) between $z_0$ and the nearest point to it such that $f(z_1)$ is not analytic. In the case of the logarithm, the only non-analytic point is $z_1=0$ which is a branch point. Thus, $R=|1-0| = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain
$$
log(3)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{3k+1}+\frac{1}{3k+2}-\frac{2}{3k+3}\right)
$$

from Taylor series for $log(1+x+x^2)$ about $x=0$.